# How to generate a 1D Gaussian filter in Julia?

Tags: julia

I have an array which I want to filter using a Gaussian filter, similarly to `scipy.ndimage.filter.gaussian_filter1d` in Python.

What package would work best for this, and how would I use it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Julia, the [ImageFiltering.jl](https://github.com/JuliaImages/ImageFiltering.jl) package can help you do this.

You can construct a 1D Gaussian kernel by `ker = ImageFiltering.Kernel.gaussian((3,))` (the tuple is passed to represent the dimension of the desired output).

Then, if you have an array of data in `data`, you can perform the filtering operation by:

```
newdata = imfilter(data, ker)
```

If you want to do in-place filtering, there is also `imfilter!`.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to `Kernel.gaussian((σ,))`, there is also `KernelFactors.IIRGaussian((σ,))`,
which constructs an infinite-impulse response approximation to the Gaussian. This can be useful for very fast approximate-Gaussian filtering when `σ` is fairly large.